# Cannot get the content inside the child tag with JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I am trying to extract the content from a gpx file. The problem is when I used getChildren("wpt") to get the content of wpt tag, I got nothing returned. And when I used getChildren() method, I got  and several  returned. And when I removed all the contents in the  only leave it as , everything works fine.

The content of this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <gpx  version="1.0" creator="GPSBabel- 
     http://www.gpsbabel.org"   
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"   
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0
     http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
            <time>2010-11-07T06:21:28Z</time> 
            <bounds minlat="40.516437500" minlon="-79.759539000"
             maxlat="44.943992000" maxlon="-72.186828500"/>
             <wpt lat="43.449895700" lon="-79.759539000">   
                  <name>Pharmacy</name>   
                  <cmt>Pharmacy</cmt>   
                  <desc>Pharmacy</desc> 
             </wpt> 
             <wpt lat="43.650977000" lon="-79.758495300">   
               <name>Pharmacy:Walk-In Clinic</name>  
               <cmt>Pharmacy:Walk-In Clinic</cmt>   
               <desc>Pharmacy:Walk-In Clinic</desc> 
            </wpt> 
            <wpt lat="43.583929100" lon="-79.758268700">   
               <name>Hospital:Meadowvale Professional Center</name>   
               <cmt>Hospital:Meadowvale Professional Center</cmt>   
               <desc>Hospital:Meadowvale Professional Center</desc>
           </wpt>
           </gpx>
```

Below is my codes to extract the content:

```
import org.jdom.*; 
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder; 
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadXml 
{
     public  Connection conn = null;
     public  Statement stmt = null ;

     public void readXml()
     {

         try
         {
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance(); 
            String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=admin";//
                   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
                   stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE); 
         }
         catch(Exception sqlexception)
         {
            System.out.println("connection error ！");
         }

        try
        { 
          SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();


          Document doc = sb.build("new_york_Government_and_Public_Services.gpx");
          Element root = doc.getRootElement();
              String name = "" ,lat = "", lon = "";
          Element elms = null;
              List list1 = root.getChildren("wpt");
          for(int i=0; i< list1.size(); i++)
          { 
              elms = (Element)list1.get(i);        
              lat = elms.getAttributeValue("lat");
              lon = elms.getAttributeValue("lon");
              name = elms.getChildText("name");
              String sql = "insert into poi_test(name,lat,lon)values               ('"+name+"','"+lat+"','"+lon+"')";
              stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

          }//for

          stmt.close(); 
          conn.close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }


     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          ReadXml rx = new ReadXml();
                  rx.readXml();
     }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but what do you think happens with the name "Children's Hospital"? Your `String sql = "insert into poi_test(name,lat,lon)values               ('"+name+"','"+lat+"','"+lon+"')";` line is fragile (the `'` in "Children's" will prematurely terminate the value string), and susceptible to SQL injection (how much can you trust your source for the gfx file?). Recommend `PreparedStatement` with `?` parameters instead. Search for "sql injection PreparedStatement" and you'll find a lot of examples.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getChildren(String) JavaDoc](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getChildren%28java.lang.String%29):

*This returns a List of all the child elements nested directly (one level deep) within this element with the **given local name and belonging to no namespace**, returned as Element objects. If this target element has no nested elements with the given name outside a namespace, an empty List is returned. The returned list is "live" in document order and changes to it affect the element's actual contents.*

As your `wpt` tag belongs to `http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0` namespace, the `getChildren` method behaves correctly when returning no children. Instead, you should use `getChildren(String,Namespace)`:

```
Namespace gpx = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0");
//[...]
List list1 = root.getChildren("wpt", gpx);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the element namespace in this instance:

```
//yada yada
Namespace rootNamespace = root.getNamespace();
List wptElements = root.getChildren("wpt", rootNamespace);
for (Iterator wptIt = wptElements.iterator(); wptIt.hasNext(); ) {
  Element wpt = (Element)wptIt.next();
  //yada yada
}
```

Please also note that its recommended to iterate through the list via an Iterator instead of by index, according to the JDOM javadocs:

> Sequential traversal through the List
>   is best done with a Iterator since the
>   underlying implement of List.size()
>   may not be the most efficient.